# sap ui5: error while running inside docker

Tags: node.js, docker, ui5-tooling

I am trying to run sap ui5 application inside docker.The docker final command runs the script in package.json as
"dock": "ui5 serve -o index.html --accept-remote-connections", But when running this am getting the following error

**Process Failed With Error
Error Message:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status').**

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: As the error states the value or object being read doesn't have any status value on which possibly you are doing some calculation. So, its throwing an error. Is it working fine without docker ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your application has a code similar to [this fix](https://github.com/codalab/codalab-worksheets/pull/3807/files):

```js
if (error.response.status === 404) {
```

Replace it with:

```js
if (error.response && error.response.status === 404) {
```

Comment: ...or use `?.` optional chaining operator.

Comment: @SUTerliakov Indeed. You can edit the answer to illustrate what it would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command instead and see what the output is:

```
ui5 serve --accept-remote-connections --verbose
```

Without context, your error could be caused by many things. The above command should provide more information, which can help you identifying the cause.

Typically you also do not want to use the `-o` (or `--open`) flag in docker. It will attempt to launch a browser, which is often not available in a docker container. This might cause issues too.

Reference: https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/pages/CLI/#ui5-serve